# Cannot change state of Array due to "Order and size of this array must remain constant" Error

Tags: reactjs, use-state

Whenever I upload a new set of files React throws the following error:

> Warning: The final argument passed to useEffect changed size between
> renders. The order and size of this array must remain constant.
> Previous: [] Incoming: [[object Object]]

Here is the code I am using:

```
export default function Files({ onChange }) {
    // Step #1: initially `files` is an empty Array
    const [files, setFiles] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
      // step #3: Notify the parent of the change
      // `files` could be empty or not at this pointt
      onChange(files)
    }, files)

    async function onFilesChange() {
      let newFiles = await getNewFiles(...arguments)
      
      // Step #2: Now `files` becomes a populated Array of any give size
      setFiles(newFiles)

      // setState is async so I cannot notify the parent 
      // of the change right away by calling onChange() below:
        
      // onChange(newFiles)

      // I need to rely on useEffect() instead (see step #3)
    }

    function onFilesRemoved() {
      // empty the `files` array and notify parent via `useEffect()`
      setFiles([])
    }

    return (
      <>
        <input type="file" multiple onChange={onFilesChange}/>
        <button onClick={onFilesRemoved}>remove files</button>
      </>
    )
}
```

The error doesn't make sense to me. The size of the array will necessarily vary from one upload to the next or if the user selects to remove all files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of the useEffect hook must be an **array** of dependencies.

Replace `files`with `[files]`and it should work.

Comment: Exactly, I would answer that!

Comment: You're right (!). This solved it. But I have a question: Since there can only be one instance of `useState()` inside a functional component and therefore only one single `state`, how could there be any other "dependencies" other than that single state itself ? I thought that `useEffect` is triggered only by a change in the `state`. If 
 it can be triggered by a change in any type of variables then I don't even need to use `useState()`. I could just declare simple `let ..` variables and pass them as dependencies. Am I correct ?

Comment: Well, actually, you can have as many instances of `useState` as you want inside a component

Comment: Thanks I hadn't realised that. I also just realised that I need to pass a new array to `setFiles()` every time, as in: `setFiles([...newFiles])`. React is so unnecessarily verbose. It's really weird that it's not using something like `computed()` like Vue or Ember. Anyway.. Thanks for the help.